# Modifying or Changing Min, Max and Displayed values for NumberPicker

Tags: android, numberpicker

I have a number picker for minutes. Initially I set displayed values to 15minute intervals.
ie, 0,15,30, 45  which means Min is 1 and max is 4.
On user selecting a menu option, I want to dynamically change the same Number picker to
have 5 minute intervals which means displayed values will be 0,5,10... 50,55   Min will remain 1 and max will be 12.

It works fine with initial settings for both types. However, I am getting array out of index when I try to modify the max value or displayed values. The issue occurs when changing the characteristics both ways ie 15 to 5 or 5 to 15 minute intervals.

Question is am I doing something wrong or is this not possible at all with number pickers.
My sample code is below. thanks.

```
private void setMinsPicker(String opt) {
    String[] mins15 = { "0", "15", "30", "45" };
    String[] mins5 = { "0", "5", "10", "15", "20", "25", "30", "35", "40",
            "45", "50", "55" };
    final String[] mins;

    if (opt == "15") {
        mins = mins15;
    } else {
        mins = mins5;
    }

    numPickerMinutes = (NumberPicker) findViewById(R.id.pMinutes);

    int ml = mins.length;

    numPickerMinutes.setMinValue(1);
    numPickerMinutes.setDisplayedValues(mins);
    numPickerMinutes.setMaxValue(ml);
}
```

Answer (score 33):

It appears to happen because when the NumberPicker detects a change in either the display values or max value it attempts to refresh the view values (i.e. access the display values array).  So if you set a display values that is smaller than `maxValue - minValue` it'll throw the `ArrayOutOfBoundsException` and similarly if you set a max value that is greater than the current it'll throw the exception aw well.  If you set the display values to null before changing the min/max values the view will default back to just showing the value and won't access the array at all.

So in your case I'd do something like so...

```
private void setMinsPicker(String opt) {
    String[] mins15 = { "0", "15", "30", "45" };
    String[] mins5 = { "0", "5", "10", "15", "20", "25", "30", "35", "40",
            "45", "50", "55" };
    final String[] mins;

    if (opt == "15") {
        mins = mins15;
    } else {
        mins = mins5;
    }

    numPickerMinutes = (NumberPicker) findViewById(R.id.pMinutes);

    int ml = mins.length;

    // Prevent ArrayOutOfBoundExceptions by setting
    // values array to null so its not checked
    numPickerMinutes.setDisplayedValues(null);

    numPickerMinutes.setMinValue(1);
    numPickerMinutes.setMaxValue(ml);
    numPickerMinutes.setDisplayedValues(mins);
}
```